# Method of Characteristic and IVP

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Using the method of characteristic determine $u(x,t)$ when

$u_t + 2xu_x = x$ , $u(x,0)=cos (x)$.

I let $v(t) = u((x(t), t)$. I determined $v(t)$ using integration by parts. My answer for $u(x,t)$ came out to be $cos(xe^{-2t}) + \frac{x(2t-1)}{4}$. However, based on the initial condition $u(x,0)=cos (x)$, I do not think I am correct.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is close.  Just writing $\dot{x}=2x$, $\dot{t}=1$, $\dot{z}=x$  with $x(0)=x_0$, $t(0)=0$ and $z(0)=\cos(x_0)$, gives $u(x,t)=z(x_0,t)=\cos(xe^{-2t})+\frac{x}{2}(1-e^{-2t})$.

Comment: can you explain how you got the $\frac{x}{2}(1-e^{-2t})$ term?

Comment: Let $s$ parametrize the characteristic, then $t=s,$ $x=x_0 e^{2s}$ and $z=\frac{x_0}{2}e^{2s}+C$. For the integration constant $C$ we get the Cauchy data $C=\cos(x_0)-\frac{x_0}{2}$, therefore $u(x,t)=z(s) = \frac{x_0}{2}(e^{2t}-1)+\cos(x_0)$. It remains to find the value $x_0$ so that $(x,t)$ is on the characteristic starting at $(x_0,0)$; in our case we can use the solution $x=x_0 e^{2t}$ to find $x_0=e^{-2t}x$.